# a two-dimensional array as a params value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I just finished Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial.  The final chapter is quite complex.  The tutorial throughout the book basically creates a site where Users can post Microposts.  Also, each User can Follow any other User and then the following User's Microposts will show up on the original User's Micropost feed.

My question has to do with why the create action inside the RelationshipsController has the params variable contain a two-dimensional array.

Here's the code.

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id", 
      class_name: "Relationship", dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower
end
```

**Micropost**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Relationship**

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
end
```

**I think this is the code that creates the two-dimensional params variable (but why?)**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id), remote: true) do       
    |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**RelationshipsController**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController  
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

So maybe I just answered my own question, but I've never seen a two-dimensional array for a params variable.  Can someone maybe shed some light on this?

oh, maybe I should post my routes.rb file as well:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'
end
```

thanks,
mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer:

This is not a 2-dimensional array, it is a nested associative array. The reason you use it is to get at the field that you actually want.

---

Long Aswer:

Assumption from tutorial: When a user clicks the follow button, the goal is to call `current_user.follow!(other_user)`. I'll walk you through how the code is achieving this. All of the magic is in the Relationship Controller and the form_for function in the view.

First, you make a form for a new relationship. Because it is a nested resource, you build it through the association.

```
current_user.relationships.build
```

But a brand new Relationship object that only corresponds to one user doesn't mean much. Instead, pass in an associative array of values to initialize the object to. In this case, the other user's id. So you assign the :followed_id attribute of the Relationship object you are building to @user.id, or the user you are trying to follow.

```
current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id)
```

When you form_for on an object, you can access the attributes of the object. In this case if we look at the Relationship model, only :followed_id is accessible.

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id
```

Finally, we need to capture the followed_id in the form submission because the goal of the form is to be able to call `current_user.follow!(other_user)` when the follow button is clicked. So we pass in the followed_id as a hidden field so it is accessible in `params` in the controller, but also the user does not see it in the view itself.

```
  <%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %>
```

Finally, when the button is clicked, because the form is for a new Relationship object, the create action is called for the Relationship controller. In there, to access the relationship object corresponding to the form you do it the same way as other forms in the tutorial -

```
params[:relationship]
```

But you don't want the relationship object, you want the user object of the one to follow so you can call `follow!`. This is easy. Just find the user in the database from the id. How to get the followed_id? It is an attribute of the Relationship object from the form.

```
params[:relationship][:followed_id]
```

---

I think its worth noting that when you make a new user object, you use params[:user]. This is just an associative array and you could access fields of it if you wanted to like

```
params[:user][:name]
```

Hopefully that made sense. It is just an nested associative array Rails uses to keep track of parameters such as those from submitting a form.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @AJcodez!  I've been messing around with Rails, read numerous books for a few months and have not been able to get to the "aha" moment.  I'm coming from PHP and am just having a tough time getting my head around Rails (maybe I'm not as smart as I thought).  But thanks for the detailed answer.  It makes sense.

Comment: One quick question though.  Is the value in :followed_id for f.hidden_field the same value as in @user.id that's passed into current_user.relationships.build?

Comment: Thats exactly it -- the form_for gives you access to the attributes of the object the form is for. That is why you need to pass in f and call f.{field_type}... 

I think youre gonna really like rails and ruby if you dont already :)